# Segmentation fault when printing strtok tokens

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf, output, strtok

I am attempting to take a line of user input from stdin using `fgets`, tokenize it with `strtok`, and then print each token to make sure it was tokenized correctly. My code is as follows:

```
char buffer[256];
char *token;`
fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);
token=strtok(buffer," \n\t()<>|&;");

while(token!=NULL) {
        printf("%s",token);
        count++;
        token = strtok(NULL," \n\t()<>|&;");
}
```

I get a segmentation fault whenever I get to the `printf` call, however, and I can't seem to figure out exactly why.

Comment: I've just tested it and it works fine. Are you sure you don't get the segfault from a different part of the program?

Comment: A short program using just this code appears to work fine without a segmentation fault. Can you post a code snippet that fails?

Comment: @MartinMajer Putting just the code above in the main function causes a segfault whenever I run it, no matter what I input. Adding prints to test where the fault happens, it appears to be on the printf that prints the token, as a print that occurs before that point will execute, but I get a segfault before a subsequent print would.

Comment: @qwrrty Putting just the code above in the main function causes a segfault whenever I run it, no matter what I input. Adding prints to test where the fault happens, it appears to be on the printf that prints the token, as a print that occurs before that point will execute, but I get a segfault before a subsequent print would.

Comment: @user3035026 I believe you, but we won't be able to diagnose the problem unless we can reproduce it. It's nigh-certain that the code you've pasted isn't *exactly* the code that's being run -- for example, the extra `` ` `` character and the undeclared `count` variable -- so seeing a [complete, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) would help a lot in understanding why your program is failing.

Comment: @qwrrty Looks like I should've pasted the whole program as you said, the issue ended up being just a forgotten `#include`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I changed your code into a complete program, cf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[256];
    char *token;
    int count = 0;
    fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);
    token=strtok(buffer," \n\t()<>|&;");

    while(token!=NULL) {
        printf("%s\n",token);
        count++;
        token = strtok(NULL," \n\t()<>|&;");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when I run it in it's original form it works

```
bash $ ./a.out
the quick brown fox
thequickbrownfoxbash $
```

Although of course there are no spaces or newlines.  When I add the `\n`, (as in code above) I get

```
bash $ ./a.out
the quick brown fox
the
quick
brown
fox
bash $
```

Now, note that I had to remove your back-tick (I assume it was a typo) and I had to declare your `count` variable, but given that it works.

From this I deduce that you probably have code around the fragment you showed us that's at fault.

Comment: I was confused as to why I was still getting segfaults after reading all the comments and answers here. Then I re-looked at yours and realized that I stupidly forgot to `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Huh. It wouldn't even compile for me without it. (From which you may deduce that I had to add it myself :-)

Comment: I thought it was kind of strange that it compiled without it as well. But adding it in there fixed the issue!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a problem with your code (aside from the stray `` ` `` at the end of the second line, which I assume isn't in your actual code).

However, this line:

```
        printf("%s",token);
```

will never print any newline, which means that it will never flush the output buffer. So if you have a segmentation fault later in your program, it might *look* like it's happening before you print the first token, simply because it prevents the output buffer from ever being flushed.

For debugging purposes, try changing the above to this:

```
        printf("%s\n",token);
```

and seeing what gets printed before the segfault.